# How to optimize an update of a column using values from another table's column?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a problem for updating a field from table `t1`, taking values from same field from table `t2`. My problem is that table `t1` has 10 millons of records and table `t2` has 20000.

When I run this:

```
update cajas t1
set t1.anio   = (select anio from tempos_Cajas t2
              where t1.cliente_codigo = t2.cliente_codigo
              and t1.caja_codigo = t2.caja_codigo
              and t1.caja_numero = t2.caja_numero
              and t1.cliente_codigo = '115')
where exists(select * from tempos_Cajas t2
              where t1.cliente_codigo = t2.cliente_codigo
              and t1.caja_codigo = t2.caja_codigo
              and t1.caja_numero = t2.caja_numero)
```

The command is running several hours and I cannot Update the field.

I'm not an Oracle expert but I wish to know if there is any way to optimize the SQL statement?

Comment: Are you sure there is no locking involved while doing the update?

Comment: Also the where exists should be replaced with IN, will be faster

Comment: Your query has no "table a" or "table b".

Comment: Finally get rid of the t1.anio = inline sql you can start thinking in terms of UPDATE (
   subquery-with-a-join
)
SET cola=colb

Comment: Thanks Ted,
Locked? mmm I don't think so, There are another process running with same user and same table in the database, and the table cajas has a composite primary key, thats the reason for using several "ands"

Comment: Thanks Gordon
Cajas is table a, and tempos_cajas is table b. When I wrote a and b that was for expressing it like an example

Comment: I am puzzled. To update, you select anio from t2, from a correlated subquery where you require that cliente_codigo be the same in the two tables **and** that the cliente_codigo be the specific value `115`? Then perhaps the `where` clause is the problem - you don't have that condition (on the specific value), so when the three column values do match, but the `cliente_codigo` is not 115, then the `anio` will be updated - to `NULL`! Is that the desired result? What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Mathguy. when match, I must take the values from anio field from tempos_cajas and update anio in table cajas. When the 3 columns don't match then not update table cajas. There is a composite primary key (cliente_codigo, caja_codigo, caja_numero)

Comment: And I add the condition cliente_codigo= '115' because our database has 40 millions of records aprox, but cliente_codigo = '115' has like 10 millions.
It's a huge database, thats my problem, because with smaller databases that command would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For your query, you want a composite index on `tempos_Cajas(cliente_codigo, caja_codigo, caja_numero, anio)`.

That said, I think the logic you want is:

```
update cajas t1
    set t1.anio   = (select anio
                     from tempos_Cajas t2
                     where t1.cliente_codigo = t2.cliente_codigo and
                           t1.caja_codigo = t2.caja_codigo and
                           t1.caja_numero = t2.caja_numero
                    )
    where exists (select 1
                  from tempos_Cajas t2
                  where t1.cliente_codigo = t2.cliente_codigo and
                        t1.caja_codigo = t2.caja_codigo and
                        t1.caja_numero = t2.caja_numero
                 ) and
          t1.cliente_codigo = '115';
```

In addition to the above index, you want an index on `cajas(cliente_codigo)`.  If the type of `cliente_codigo` is numeric, then get rid of the single quotes on the constant.

Comment: the composite index is(cliente_codigo, caja_codigo, caja_numero); And the data type is:
cliente_codigo  (varchar),
caja_codigo (varchar),
caja_numero (numeric).
And I already try with the logic you wrote. Result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days the advice would be to use `IN` for situations where the driving table - `t1` - is huge and the table in the subquery - `t2` - is small. `WHERE EXISTS` was deemed more suitable for situations where that ratio is flipped. Your numbers ( `t1` = 10,000,000 and `t2` = 20,000) fit the first scenario.

However, the Oracle optimizer has grown cleverer over the years. Given your posted situation - composite index on `t1(cliente_codigo, caja_codigo, caja_numero)`, no index on `t2` - this update produces the same explain plan as your `where exists` version (on 11gR2 and 12cR2):

```
update cajas t1
set t1.anio   = (select anio from tempos_Cajas t2
              where t1.cliente_codigo = t2.cliente_codigo
              and t1.caja_codigo = t2.caja_codigo
              and t1.caja_numero = t2.caja_numero)
where (t1.cliente_codigo, t1.caja_codigo, t1.caja_numero) in  
       (select t2.cliente_codigo, t2.caja_codigo, t2.caja_numero 
        from tempos_Cajas t2)
;
```

The plan is like this:

```
SQL> 
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1411510459

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name        | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | UPDATE STATEMENT     |             |    30M|  1230M|       |   900M  (4)|999:59:59 |
|   1 |  UPDATE              | T1          |       |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN SEMI    |             |    30M|  1230M|       |   136   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN   | T1_COMP_IDX |    30M|   801M|       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    SORT UNIQUE       |             | 20000 |   292K|  1112K|   136   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| T2          | 20000 |   292K|       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | T2          |     1 |    28 |       |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("T1"."CLIENTE_CODIGO"="T2"."CLIENTE_CODIGO" AND
              "T1"."CAJA_CODIGO"="T2"."CAJA_CODIGO" AND "T1"."CAJA_NUMERO"="T2"."CAJA_NUMERO")
       filter("T1"."CAJA_NUMERO"="T2"."CAJA_NUMERO" AND
              "T1"."CAJA_CODIGO"="T2"."CAJA_CODIGO" AND
              "T1"."CLIENTE_CODIGO"="T2"."CLIENTE_CODIGO")
   6 - filter("T2"."CLIENTE_CODIGO"=:B1 AND "T2"."CAJA_CODIGO"=:B2 AND
              "T2"."CAJA_NUMERO"=:B3)

24 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It's a fairly disastrous plan because it hits every row in the driving table. A better solution is to use MERGE instead.

```
merge into t1
    using ( select * from t2 ) t2
    on (t1.cliente_codigo = t2.cliente_codigo
        and   t1.caja_codigo = t2.caja_codigo
        and   t1.caja_numero = t2.caja_numero)  
when matched then
    update set t1.anio = t2.anio ;
```

This has a much nicer plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 525352362

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                |             | 20000 |   507K|    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE                         | T1          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                         |             |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |             |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS               |             | 20000 |  1582K|    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL         | T2          | 20000 |   546K|    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | T1_COMP_IDX |    30M|       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| T1          |     1 |    53 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("T1"."CLIENTE_CODIGO"="T2"."CLIENTE_CODIGO" AND
              "T1"."CAJA_CODIGO"="T2"."CAJA_CODIGO" AND "T1"."CAJA_NUMERO"="T2"."CAJA_NUMERO")
```

Please remember that explain plans are indicative, and that goes double for plans using toy tables with faked statistics, so please benchmark the different approaches on realistic data structures.